# Integration - Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and $g\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ can we prove that:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x)\,dx\leq \|g\|_\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \, dx$$
Or, even an approximate inequality where on the the right side we still have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\,dx$

Comment: By monotonicity of the integral we have the inequality $$\left\lvert\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) g(x)\,\mathrm dx\right\rvert \le\|g\|_\infty \| f\|_1$$

Comment: I want it without absolute value |.|

Comment: Well $$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) g(x)\,\mathrm dx \le\|g\|_\infty \| f\|_1$$ is also true (it is in fact a corollary of the above inequality...) But your inequality is wrong: Take for example $f(x)=-\exp(-x^2)$ and $g(x)=-1$.

Comment: Instead of $\displaystyle (\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) g(x) \,dx)$ one can write $\displaystyle \left(\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) g(x) \,dx\right)$ (but I deleted the parenthesis altogether). I also put a small space between $g(x)$ and $dx$ and between $f(x)$ and $dx.$ And I changed $||g||$ to $\|g\|.$ If that last change is not conspicuous to you consider the typographical difference between $||f|| ||g||$ (coded as ||f|| ||g||) and $\|f\|\|g\|$ (coded as \|f\|\|g\|). $\qquad$

Comment: but what if $g$ is positive

Answer (score 0):

Any instance in which $f$ and $g$ are everywhere negative is a counterexample.

But if you have $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|\,dx$ instead of $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\,dx$ on the right side, then it's true, thus:
\begin{align}
& \left| \int\limits_{\mathbb R} f(x)g(x)\, dx \right| \\[8pt]
\le {} & \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)||g(x)|\,dx \\[8pt]
\le {} & \int\limits_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| \|g\|_\infty \, dx = \|g\|_\infty \int\limits_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|\,dx \\[8pt]
= {} & \|g\|_\infty \|f\|_1.
\end{align}

Comment: $f(x)g(x)\le f(x)\| g(x)\|_{\infty} $ holds only when $f(x)$ is non-negative. So, we need to use $|f|$ instead of $f$ throughout the calculation.

Comment: Thus, it should be $\left|\int fg\right| \le \int |fg| \le \int |f| \|g\|_\infty =\|g\|_\infty\| f \|_1$

Comment: @AdityaGhosh : fixed. Thank you.